# $T: l^p(\mathbb{N})\rightarrow L^p([0,+\infty),dx)$ is a isometry

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $1\le p<+\infty$ and let $T:l^p(\mathbb{N}) \rightarrow L^p([0,+\infty),dx)$ an application defined by

$T(a)(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n\mathbb{1}_{[n-1,n)}(x),\forall a=(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\in l^p(\mathbb{N}),\forall x\in[0,+\infty)$.

Show that $T$ is an isometry.

I need to prove that

$||T(a)||_{L^p}=||a||_{l^p}$.

Let $X=[0,+\infty)$

$||T(a)||_{L^p}=(\int_X |T(a)(x)|^p)^{1/p}=(\int_X |\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}a_n\mathbb{1}_{[n-1,n)}(x)|^p)^{1/p}$.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Note that $1_{[n,n+1)} \cdot 1_{[k,k+1)}= \delta_{nk}$ (This may give you an hint on what $(1_{[n,n+1)} + 1_{[k,k+1)})^p$ might be)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you are stuck somewhere wondering what is $|\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n\mathbf{1}_{[n-1,n)}(x)|^p$?

If $x_0\in X:=[0,\infty)$ then $x_0\in [n_0-1,n_0)$ for some $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$. Hence: $$\bigg|\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n\mathbf{1}_{[n-1,n)}(x_0)\bigg|^p=|a_{n_0}\mathbf{1}_{[n_0-1,n_0)}(x_0)|^p=|a_{n_0}|^p$$ We may conclude that  $$\bigg|\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n\mathbf{1}_{[n-1,n)}(x)\bigg|^p=\sum_{n\geq 1}|a_n|^p \mathbf{1}_{[n-1,n)}(x)$$
Integrating  and using [The Monotone Convergence Theorem](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem)  (MCT) yields:
\begin{align}
\Vert T(a)\Vert_{L^p}^p&=\int_X \bigg|\sum_{n\geq 1} a_n\mathbf{1}_{[n-1,n)}(x)\bigg|^p\,dx\\
&=\int_X\sum_{n\geq 1}|a_n|^p \mathbf{1}_{[n-1,n)}(x)\,dx\\
&\stackrel{MCT}{=}\sum_{n\geq 1 }\int_X|a_n|^p \mathbf{1}_{[n-1,n)}(x)\,dx\\
&=\sum_{n\geq 1} |a_n|^p\\
&=\Vert a\Vert_{l^p}^p
\end{align}
Taking $p$-th root gives the desired result.

Comment: Thanks!, I forgot the result of MTC .